# Need an optimized way to return distinct rows in a table

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I had a table (with no keys) having approximately 35 Million records and the over 250+ columns.
When i tried to get the distinct rows for that table in snowflake, it's taking nearly 12 minutes of time.
Is there any way to get the result faster ?

I have tried different ways of writing the code (distinct, Group By, subqueries, CTE ..etc) but in every case, it took nearly 12minutes of time.

Comment: Whatever you try is going to have to compare every column on every row so is never going to be fast. One approach that may make the actual comparison faster (but possibly not the overall time) would be to create a hash of all the column values in each row and then compare the hashes to find distinct values

Comment: I think, 12 minutes - is god result. You are lucky). You can add permanent column with rank()over(order by <all columns>)

Comment: i think it make more sense to create a unique key column. Every table should have a unique keys, else it will be very difficult to use it. I know some cases we cant have it but in the long run you will face more issues with a keyless table than a table with 10 columns concatenated as keys. You will never know if your data is correct/duplicated.

Comment: The 12 minute is not bad but it depends upon How frequently are you going to run this Select distinct column query , is it once a day or once a week or a month or many times in a day ?

Comment: Try adding the cluster key on few of columns, this will help snowflake engine to reduce the comparison by better partition pruning.